# How to figure out what mtd device is attached to which ubi volume(s)

Tags: linux, flash-memory, ubifs

I cannot find a way to figure out which ubi device is attached to which mtd device. For instance, ubi0 can be attached to mtd1 and ubi1 to mtd0.

Does anyone know a way to figure out which is connected to which?

Answer (score 8):

```
cat /sys/devices/virtual/ubi/ubi0/mtd_num
```